# How can i remove the head line of excel in for loop output

Tags: python, excel, jupyter-notebook

I want to only show the output without the head line but it kept printing

```
for i in range(0,10):
    print (df.loc[i:i])
```

How can I only show the values without the headlines printed or to hide in the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the actual values by indexing the series that you get out. If you first interpret it as a NumPy array, you can get the values you'd like

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    line = df.loc[i].to_numpy()
    print(line[0], line[1])
```